# closing a dialog after a delay

Tags: visual-c++, dialog

After calling DoModal() on a dialog, and calling a delay function. how do you close the dialog.

m_dlg.DoModal();
Sleep(1000);
.
.
.

Answer (score 1):

Modal dialogs are modal in the sense that they are shown when you enter DoModal and hidden when DoModal is left. Your dialog is already closed before you call Sleep(1000);

You should use a non-modal dialog for this purpose.

m_dlg.ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
Sleep(1000);
m_dlg.ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);

Comment: how do you use a non-modal dialog?

Comment: You create it first and then call ShowWindow.
Have a look at this. There is an example there as well. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhth57kd(VS.80).aspx